# how to convert `content://media/external/images/media/Y` to `file:///storage/sdcard0/Pictures/X.jpg` in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to upload image to Google Drive from my android app,

based on this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android).

When I debug their sample project I see a typical fileUri =

`file:///storage/sdcard0/Pictures/IMG_20131117_090231.jpg`

In my app I want to upload an existing photo.

I retrieve its path like that

```
     private void GetAnyImage()
        {
            File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures/Screenshots"); 
                              // --> /storage/sdcard0/Pictures/Screenshots

            Log.d("File path ", dir.getPath());
            String dirPath=dir.getAbsolutePath();
            if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_ID);
            }  
        }
```

and eventually get this typical fileUri =`content://media/external/images/media/74275`

however when running this line of code

```
  private void saveFileToDrive() {

    //  progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          // File's binary content
          java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
          FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", fileContent);

      // File's metadata.
      File body = new File();
      body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
      body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");

      File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
```

I get an error:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/74275: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

how can I solve this?

how to convert `content://media/external/images/media/Y` to `file:///storage/sdcard0/Pictures/X.jpg` ?

Comment: I have the same problem but I have it in specific device, Anyone has idea why is that so ?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Will something like this work for you? What this does is query the content resolver to find the file path data that is stored for that content entry

```
public static String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This will end up giving you an absolute file path that you can construct a file uri from

Comment: how do u implement it?

Comment: This absolutely fixed the problem for me. One question though, is there a min or max API that this will not work on? IE, if they are API 24+ or Below Api 14 will this not work for some reason?

Comment: @Silmarilos, no idea, I wrote this code for a project a couple of years ago and things have definitely changed in that time. In regards to min level compatibility, the column we are searching here from `MediaStore.Images.Media` inherits from `MediaStore.MediaColumns` which contains the `Data` definition [documented here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#DATA). It was added in API 1 so it should work consistently across platforms.

Comment: @Selecsosi how to get the path if the file is an pdf or video or xls??

Comment: Images.Media.DATA is deprecated , u have any solution for this ? @Selecsosi

Answer (score 8):

If you just want the bitmap, This too works

```
InputStream inputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
if( inputStream != null ) inputStream.close();
```

sample uri : content://media/external/images/media/12345