# Uri points to deleted file but still displays in app, how?

Tags: android, uri, mediastore

From inside my app, I take a picture using my camera. This picture is then loaded into an `ImageView` using its `Uri` which would look something like this: `content://media/external/images/media/12345`. I can get the path of this `Uri` by [querying the `MediaStore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20059657/5437165), it looks something like this: `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_12345.jpg`.

I now manually delete the image from that path above. But when I reopen the app, the image is still there and accessible under the same `Uri`. If I query the `MediaStore` again it gives me a `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`. So the file does not exist to the `MediaStore`

So what's happening here? If I've deleted the file manually, then it should not be available to the app. Where is this file right now? Is there a better way of deleting images such that they are removed from everywhere?

Comment: You may want to read about _caching_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache

Comment: @Psi Are you saying that if I restarted my device, this image would no longer be available?

Comment: You have to clean your browser cache, i explain that in my answer

Comment: How are you deleting the app? Are you using a file manager or are you using an app that updates the MediaStore? Also, is the directory where the image stored synced with some sort of cloud storage, such as google pictures?

Comment: @PeriHartman I am using a file manager to delete it

Comment: @PeriHartman He does not delete an app, he just deletes the source image on the server.

Comment: Try deleting the picture using the Gallery app (which also updates MediaStore) and see if your problem goes away. Also, you didn't say, but is it possible the file is getting refreshed from cloud storage?

Comment: The file manager has no good way of telling the `MediaStore` that the file is being deleted. When adding files, we can use `MediaScannerConnection` for that. The `MediaStore` will eventually update its index, but that may take several hours.

Comment: @CommonsWare How about if I delete the file from inside my app and send `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` intent?

Comment: That's the problem: what exactly are you going to tell that `Intent` to scan? I haven't looked into this much. It's possible that using that `Intent` or `MedisScannerConnection` with the parent directory will work. Or, perhaps using the now-deleted file's path will work. It's also possible that neither will work.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is it guaranteed that MediaStore will take care of it itself? Or can the image be recovered in some way? If it's the former, then it doesn't matter much if the Uri remains for a few extra hours

Comment: "Is it guaranteed that MediaStore will take care of it itself?" -- it should. "Or can the image be recovered in some way?" -- that should not be possible. The filesystem is the "system of record" in this case. `MediaStore` is just an index. To draw an analogy: if you delete a Web page, a search engine like Google will still say that it exists for a while, until it crawls that site again. While Google (and perhaps other search engines) may cache selected Web pages, `MediaStore` does not, because these are phones, not server farms, and it does not have the space.

Comment: @CommonsWare I was with you until that last sentence. If there is no cache, then how is the image displayed when the actual file has been deleted?

Comment: Ummm... are you sure that you are reloading the image? "Reopen the app" does not mean the same thing in Android as it would in, say, Windows. Unless you terminated your process, any in-memory cache (e.g., from an image-loading library like Picasso) would still be intact.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh boy... you were right. I was using Glide as my image-loader and it was caching it. Clearing the cache gets rid of the image. Thanks a lot! (You should put this all in an answer or I can do it myself tomorrow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MediaStore` is an index of available files. Like any index, it needs to be updated when there are changes to the filesystem. And, like a search engine, there are two main ways in which that happens:

- Somebody tells the `MediaStore` to scan something and add it to the index
- The `MediaStore` crawls the fileystem

In your case, deleting the file using a file manager may not have updated `MediaStore`, in part because there is no documentation on how to update the `MediaStore` when you delete something. The docs are focused on indexing new files, not de-listing deleted ones.

The reason why the `Uri` appeared to continue to work is because of your image-loading library (Glide, in your case). Glide has an in-memory cache, and it will use images from cache when possible.

Comment: What is the best solution to de-listing deleted files.

Comment: @NarendraSorathiya: To be honest, I am not certain what solutions exist. I have not researched this point.

Comment: I have Downloaded files using DownloadManager & then I uninstalled app, files also deleted as per new behaviour of DownloadManager but using mediaStore, i still showing that file in list.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about caching: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache

When downloading a resource (such as an image) for the first time, the browser (or most apps using a built-in http communication component) save that resource in the so-called *cache*. When it comes to reading the resource again next time, they find it has been cached locally, so they don't need to load it again over the net.

You don't have full control over the behaviour, but you can serve your resource via HTTP using the `Cache-control` and `Proxy` headers: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

If you want to remove that resource from the cache, well, you have to clean your browser cache. Usually, this can be done in the system settings or in the settings of your browser.

Comment: This for an app and not a browser, does this still apply?

Comment: As I said, if the app uses a built-in component to download resources via http, usually the local browser cache is used. Sometimes they implement an own browser cache, so have a look at their options, maybe there is a way to clear the cache.