# Android - Play video in new activity

Tags: java, android, media-player

I am trying to play a selected video in another activity by passing the fileUri to the next activity. At the moment I click on `(Button) findViewById(R.id.pickVid);` which calls `PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST` once the video is selected the new activity opens but the screen is black. I don't think the fileUri is passed correctly, any help please?

MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button pickVid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickVid);


    //choose the video
    pickVid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent chooseVideo = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            chooseVideo.setType("video/*");
            startActivityForResult(chooseVideo, PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST);
        }
    });


}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri vidFile = data.getData();
            Intent playVid = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayVideoAct.class);
            playVid.putExtra("vidFile", vidFile);
            startActivity(playVid);
        }
    }

}
```

PlayVideoAct

```
    String mStringFilePath;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_playvideo);

    mStringFilePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("vidFile");

    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    if (this.mPlayer == null) {
        this.mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    } else {
        this.mPlayer.reset();
        mPlayer.start();
    }
    try {
        FileInputStream paramSurfaceHolder = new FileInputStream(mStringFilePath);
        this.mPlayer.setDataSource(paramSurfaceHolder.getFD());
        this.mPlayer.setDisplay(this.mSurfaceHolder);
        this.mPlayer.prepare();
        this.mPlayer.start();
        this.mPlayer.pause();
        Play();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogUtil.e(e, "Error in PlayVideoAct.surfaceCreate(SurfaceHolder)");
    }
}


private void Play() {

    mMediaPlayer.start();
    if (this.mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        this.mMediaPlayer.pause();
        return;
    }
    if (this.isStop) {
        this.mMediaPlayer.seekTo(this.leftPosition);
    }
    this.mImageViewButtonControls.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);

}
```

Comment: check mStringFilePath  value using Toast.

Comment: I used `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),mStringFilePath ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` and the toast is blank?

Comment: and I get error `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Comment: convert that String to Uri, beacause you are passing uri inside Intent not String.

Comment: can you please give me an example(code snippet), I used `mVideoUri = Uri.parse(mStringFilePath);` inside onCreate and now it crashes saying `java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString`

Comment: in mainactivity you are using  Uri vidFile = data.getData(); and passing this value to playvideoAct activity.so instead of Uri , pass String

Comment: like this? `Uri vidFile = data.getData();' 'mMediaUri = Uri.parse(vidFile);` I can't get it working, if you post what I should do as code example I can mark your answer....

Comment: @santoshgore I still can't get it working

Comment: in onActivityResult method what value you are getting for vidFile  variable.and its string or uri?

Comment: I am getting the uri of the file. not string, uri

Comment: ok convert that uri to string using vidFile.toString() method and then pass that string value through Intent.

Comment: Ok now I get the file path toasted but the screen is still black

Comment: with error `open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: dont use FileInputStream ,instead of that directly call         this.mPlayer.setDataSource(mStringFilePath); and first check mStringFilePath then call ablove line

Comment: now I'm getting error `setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000`

Comment: what is your path ?its present in external or internal memory?

Comment: in the internal

Comment: but the toast I get is `content://media/external/video/media/28638`

Comment: please answer when you can

Comment: @santoshgore should I ask a new question?

Comment: just google it your error . you can easily find the solution.

Comment: i think this url will help you little bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028319/how-to-convert-content-media-external-images-media-y-to-file-storage-sdc