# Android - MediaPlayer (open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, video, media-player

I asked a question earlier [play video in new activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039320/android-play-video-in-new-activity)

What I want is when `(Button) findViewById(R.id.pickVid);` is clicked it calls `PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST`, then when the video is selected the new activity should open and play the video.

The guy that helped me said that I should use `this.mPlayer.setDataSource(mStringFilePath);` instead of `FileInputStream`

PROBLEM:

I am getting a error saying `setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000` with a black screen.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Uri mMediaUri;
String vidFile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button pickVid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickVid);

    //choose the video
    pickVid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent chooseVideo = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            chooseVideo.setType("video/*");
            startActivityForResult(chooseVideo, PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST);


        }
    });


}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mMediaUri = data.getData();
            vidFile = mMediaUri.toString();
            Intent playVid = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayVideoAct.class);
            playVid.putExtra("vidFile", vidFile);


            startActivity(playVid);
        }
    }

}
```

PlayVideoAct

```
    String mStringFilePath;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_playvideo);

    mStringFilePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("vidFile");

    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    if (this.mPlayer == null) {
        this.mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    } else {
        this.mPlayer.reset();
        mPlayer.start();
    }
    try {
        this.mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mStringFilePath);
        this.mPlayer.setDisplay(this.mSurfaceHolder);
        this.mPlayer.prepare();
        this.mPlayer.start();
        this.mPlayer.pause();
        Play();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogUtil.e(e, "Error in PlayVideoAct.surfaceCreate(SurfaceHolder)");
    }
}

private void Play() {

mMediaPlayer.start();
if (this.mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    this.mMediaPlayer.pause();
    return;
}
if (this.isStop) {
    this.mMediaPlayer.seekTo(this.leftPosition);
}
this.mImageViewButtonControls.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
```

}

Comment: *`void MediaPlayer.setDataSource (String path)` - Sets the data source (file-path or http/rtsp URL) to use.* ... **why you think that `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` returns http/rtsp or file-path ?**

Comment: @Selvin does it not? I toasted `mStringFilePath` and it returned `content://media/external/video/media/28638`

Answer (score 0):

Check video path, if it's correct then check if you have all necessary permissions like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If yes, then depending on your Android version you may need to go to Settings -> Apps -> Your application -> Permissions and toggle those permissions manually.

Comment: In such case please try hardcoding String with path to check if it's correct. E.g. set it to /sdcard/yourFile.mp4